# CakePHP 3: Set current time for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

With CakePHP 3, I'm using the built in class `Cake\I18n\Time` to calculate the difference in time from an API response and the current time. The results are getting stored for a unit test, but I don't know how to set what the current time is, so the expected results keep changing.

Here's the unit I'm trying to test:

```
$apiTime = Time::createFromTimestamp($apiTimestamp);

// Get the time the prediction was generated
$currentTime = Time::now();

return (int)(($apiTime->getTimestamp() - $currentTime->getTimestamp()) / 60);
```

So, is there any way that I can set the current time? That way I would be able to actually know what the expected results are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(from http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#creating-time-instances)

In test cases you can mock out `now()` using `setTestNow()`:

```
// Fixate time.
$now = new Time('2014-04-12 12:22:30');
Time::setTestNow($now);

// Returns '2014-04-12 12:22:30'
$now = Time::now();

// Returns '2014-04-12 12:22:30'
$now = Time::parse('now');
```

Comment: This is a feature of Carbon, on which Cake's `Time` class is based.

Comment: Cake's `Time` class is now based on Chronos. Source: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/chronos.html